# How does Bash (and other shells) handle detaching STDIN when `bg`ing a stopped process?

Tags: bash, shell, signals, zsh, jobs

I'm in the process of writing my own shell and I have support for job control[1] (akin to `jobs`). I can stop processes, resume them in the foreground and also background[2] them. That all largely works as expected - at least from the user's perspective.

However the issue I have is when resuming a job in the background any applications that read from STDIN will compete with readline (I've actually written my own readline API, for reasons out of scope of this question) and this breaks usability of the shell.

These instances are quite rare I'll admit, but my understanding is what should normally happen is any backgrounded processes that requires reading from STDIN[3] are send a SIGTTIN[4] signal.

My issue is how do I monitor that applications read from STDIN - so that I can send SIGTTIN when required?

This is where my research has come to a dead end. So I'm interested in how other shells handle this kind of problem.

Below are some references to help explain what I'm trying to do in case my description above wasn't very clear:

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_control_(Unix)#Overview

[2] https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/bg.html

[3] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_control_(Unix)#Implementation

[4] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)#SIGTTIN

Comment: this is not part of the shell but the system for example the tr command `tr 01 10 &` started in background will be stopped as trying to read from stdin and running in backgroun

Comment: however stopped doesn't mean terminated after `fg %1` or the job id it continues

Comment: Yup, the "stopped" terminology is a tad misleading but I got that part nailed down. However it sounds like I needed to re-write all of my job control logic though as I'm currently trying to handle that in the shell instead of leaving the kernel to do it's thing and setting process groups instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding:

- The shell is usually the session leader which allocates the controlling terminal.
- Each job (may have multiple processes, like `ls | wc -l`) is a process group.
- Only the foreground pgrp can read from the controlling terminal. (The fg pgrp may have multiple processes and these processes CAN read from the controlling termianl at the same time.)
- The shell calls `tcsetpgrp()` to set the foreground pgrp (e.g. when we start a new job, or put a bg job back to fg with `fg`).
- It's the kernel (tty driver) who sends `SIGTTIN` to a background process which tries to read from the controlling terminal.
- The shell does not know when a process would read from the controlling terminal. Instead, the shell monitors the job's status change. When a process is stopped by `SIGTTIN`, the shell would receive `SIGCHLD` and then it can call `waitpid()` to get more info.

Comment: It sounds like I'm doing a lot wrong at the moment then because I'm capturing the signals and then forwarding them on to the relevant process rather than letting the process handle the signals themselves and not assigning process groups. Thank you